# Use netstat to find if a specific port is free

Tags: server, free

I'd like to run a server with a specific port, but I don't know if it is free. How could I know if a specific port is free? Could I use `netstat` command for that?

Answer (score 2):

While you can `netstat` and `grep`, it's easier to `lsof`:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :22
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      913 root    3u  IPv4  63380      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      913 root    4u  IPv6  63382      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
$ sudo lsof -i :80
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 1914     root    4u  IPv6  19309      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 1917 www-data    4u  IPv6  19309      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 1945 www-data    4u  IPv6  19309      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```